# CKEditor 4.3.3 adding â€‹ with single line break

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, character-encoding, ckeditor

This is more than likely a problem to do with charset encoding. However, i'm unable to locate where the problem is occuring.

I have CKEditor 4.3.3 installed on a server and when I enter a single line break (shift+enter) I get â€‹.

I picked up on this same problem years ago:

http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/single-line-break-adding-special-characters

However, charset encoding solved the issue.

Now, i've learned from my mistakes and everything is in UTF-8 as far as I can tell. Document, js, etc.

So, what else could be causing this issue? What all could be affecting the encoding and thus these problems? Seems to only happen in Chrome too.

Comment: do you have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the `head` of your HTML ?

Comment: @webNeat yep, i've got <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   . I'm also forcing utf-8 via a PHP header. I can confirm that in Chrome dev tools that content type is coming back as text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: Is `ckeditor.js` served in UTT-8? That's the question ;). This issue occurs when it isn't or when its encoding was broken.

Comment: @Reinmar How can I check that? In Chrome Developer Tools, it only shows type, not encoding charset.